# MQTT + Unable to get response with # (hash character)

Tags: c++, mqtt

I am trying to connect with an azure cloud endpoint with a hash character (#), but unable to get a trigger for subscription callback.

**Mqtt Client:**

> libmosquitto-dev/stable,stable,now 1.5.7-1+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]

> MQTT version 3.1/3.1.1 client library, development files

Following is my complete workflow:

1. Subscribe topic with **"devices/MyDevice/messages/devicebound/#"**.
2. Call for publish() so that azure cloud will send back the acknowledgement.
3. Received a message "Client MyDevice received PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m2, **'devices/MyDevice/messages/devicebound/%24.to=%2Fdevices%2FMyDevice%2Fmessages%2Fdevicebound&tty_v3=ms', ... (207 bytes))"**
4. Subscription handler is not called.
5. Subscribe client using **"devices/MyDevice/messages/devicebound/%24.to=%2Fdevices%2FMyDevice%2Fmessages%2Fdevicebound&tty_v3=ms"**
6. Subscription handler is called.
7. Ideally subscription handler should be called even if I subscribe using # (**"devices/MyDevice/messages/devicebound/#"**).

Following is my complete logs:

```
[2021-06-28 11:14:59] [INFO] Operation: Subscribe was successful
[2021-06-28 11:14:59] [INFO]  Topic : devices/MyDevice/messages/devicebound/#
....
....
[2021-06-28 11:15:00] [INFO]  Publish QoS : 1
[2021-06-28 11:15:00] [INFO] LogCallback
[2021-06-28 11:15:00] [INFO]  Library Info Logs : Client MyDevice sending PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m2, 'devices/MyDevice/messages/events/tty_v3=m', ... (1413 bytes))
[2021-06-28 11:15:00] [INFO] Operation: Publish was successful
[2021-06-28 11:15:00] [INFO]  Publish successful to topic : devices/MyDevice/messages/events/tty_v3=m
[2021-06-28 11:15:00] [INFO] LogCallback
[2021-06-28 11:15:00] [INFO]  Library Info Logs : Client MyDevice received PUBACK (Mid: 2)
[2021-06-28 11:15:00] [INFO] OnPublishCallback
[2021-06-28 11:15:00] [INFO] Publish Callback Triggered for : MyDevice
[2021-06-28 11:15:02] [INFO] LogCallback
[2021-06-28 11:15:02] [INFO]  Library Info Logs : Client MyDevice received PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m2, 'devices/MyDevice/messages/devicebound/%24.to=%2Fdevices%2FMyDevice%2Fmessages%2Fdevicebound&tty_v3=ms', ... (207 bytes))
[2021-06-28 11:15:02] [INFO] LogCallback
[2021-06-28 11:15:02] [INFO]  Library Info Logs : Client MyDevice sending PUBACK (Mid: 2)
[2021-06-28 11:15:02] [INFO] MessageCallback
[2021-06-28 11:15:02] [INFO] Message Callback Triggered for : MyDevice
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (its easier to comment if we can see your code).

Answer (score 0):

After creating a sample program I figured out the issue is with the implementation. The application has a check to validate the subscription topic once message is received.

As subscription was made with "devices/MyDevice/messages/devicebound/#" and message is received with "devices/MyDevice/messages/devicebound/%24.to=%2Fdevices%2FMyDevice%2Fmessages%2Fdevicebound&tty_v3=ms", hence validation is failed.